# WCF Security Transport Security Questions

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm writing a set of WCF services that rely on transport security with Windows Authentication using the trusted subsystem model.  However, I want to perform authorization based on the original client user that initiated the request (e.g. a user from a website with a username/password).  I'm planning to achieve this by adding the original user's credentials in the header before the client sends the message and then the service will use the supplied credentials to authorize the user.  So I have a few questions about this implementation:

1) using transport security with windows auth, I do NOT need to worry about again encrypting the passed credentials to ensure the validity... WCF automatically takes care of this - is this correct?

2) how does this implementation prevent a malicious service, running under some windows account within the domain, to send a message tagged with spoofed credentials.  for e.g. a malicious service replaces the credentials with an Admin user to do something bad?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What binding are you using? Is this service only within your corporate LAN, or do you plan to go outside the firewall?

To answer your question (as far as I can)

1) With Windows authentication over transport security, the transport layer will be encrypted and safe - no need to worry about additional encryption of credentials etc.

2) It cannot. If a malicious service manages to "hijack" some valid Windows credentials and poses as "John Doe" who has an account on your corporate network, there's no way the WCF service can distinguish this from a valid request by John Doe.

Comment: yes this service will only be within the corporate lan, using NetTcpBinding.

2) do you know any other ways we can prevent this from happening?  or can you suggest some other kind of implementation that still allows using the trusted subsystem model, while doing authorization based on the original request?

Comment: for 2) - no, not really - but the malicious service would have to be able to hijack an existing Windows account, including its security token - I would believe inside a corporate LAN, this is rather unlikely

Comment: for 2) the only option to make it even safer is to use standard Windows impersonation, instead of packaging up the Windows credentials as clear-text yourself. Let Windows handle the impersonation aspects of it all

Comment: i'm not passing windows credentials, i'm actually passing some username credentials originally supplied by a website, so i'm not sure how i can use impersonation.

Comment: but anyway, in general, it would be secure "enough" to rely on the security of the windows account to prevent this from happening right?

Comment: can you map those usernames from the website to existing AD accounts? If not: how do you validate/authenticate those users originally on your website??

Comment: If you have a "weak" authentication system on your web site, it would likely be pretty easy for a malicious service to log on and thus hijack one of your identities. But since everything is behing the corporate firewall - why not use Windows authentication in the first place on the website??